# Laravel: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in file

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have a list using **React** & **Laravel**.
Using `axios`, I'm passing data like this on the frontend

```
async function axiospost(order){  

try {
  const response = await  axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/social/reorder/', {order});
  return response.data;

} catch (error){console.error("Not able");}

}
```

But when testing my API using https://reqbin.com/, I have the following error :

```
ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in file C:\Users\test\test\app\Http\Controllers\SocialController.php on line 105
```

And line 105 is exactly this :

```
foreach ($order as $value){
```

The controller :

```
public function reorder(Request $request)
{
   // $this->validate($request,['order'=>'required']);
    $order = $request->input('order');

    DB::transaction(function () use ($order){
        foreach ($order as $value){
            Social::find($value['id'])->update(['order'=>$value['order']]);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: `$this->validate($request,['order'=>'required','array']);` add `array` validation so you will make sure it always array to apply `foreach`

Comment: @KamleshPaul You got it perfectly right. No more error. Thank you very much man!